# `ionic package build` overwrites config.xml and icons

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I followed [these instructions](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/adding-an-icon/) to add my custom icons for my app. However, when I run `ionic package build android` from the command line, it overwrites all of the icon paths in my config.xml file back to their default values (`resources/android/icon/...`). I can't seem to get rid of the generic default icon.

I also tried overwriting the icons that came with the starter app in `resources/android/icon` but those also get overwritten.

What am I doing wrong? The process does NOT overwrite any other information in my `config.xml` such as the app name or description. Just the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are doing the wrong process, you need generate custom icons and splash screen in ionic. Follow this steps from the official docs:

[Automating icons and splash screens](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/)

[Ionic icons and splash tutorial](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html)